# Believable (-; : Awk rounding a float to integer got weird result: 123.12*100 -> 12312(good) but 1234.12*100 -> 123411(bad)

Tags: awk, integer, printf, rounding, floating

```
awk '{printf "%d\n", (1234.12*100)}' <<<""
```

outputs

```
123411
```

It is supposed to be 123412.

Awk version: GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

What am I missing?

EDIT: Weird, I did more tests:

```
$ awk '{printf "%d\n", (0.12*100)}' <<<""
12
$ awk '{printf "%d\n", (1.12*100)}' <<<""
112
$ awk '{printf "%d\n", (12.12*100)}' <<<""
1212
$ awk '{printf "%d\n", (123.12*100)}' <<<""
12312
```

so far all good.

But then get wrong:

```
$ awk '{printf "%d\n", (1234.12*100)}' <<<""
123411
```

Other forms work:

```
$ awk '{print (1234.12*100)}' <<<""
123412
$ awk '{printf "%.0f\n", (1234.12*100)}' <<<""
```

outputs `123412` correctly.

Comment: Try `awk '{printf "%.12f\n", (1234.12*100)}' <<<""`. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Output is 123411.999999999985

Comment: But `awk '{printf "%.0f\n", (1234.12*100)}' <<<""` outputs `123412`

Comment: Why is that surprising?

Comment: Both `awk '{print (1234.12*100)}' <<<""` and `awk '{printf "%.0f\n", (1234.12*100)}' <<<""` work, why the printf "\d" does not?

Comment: `%d` truncates the number, the others round it

Comment: I know there is some precision loss during storing decimal number with binary floating number, but the issue I encountered seems should not happen.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Sure %d truncates the number, 1.2 -> 1, I understand, but obviously awk know `(1234.12*100)` is `123412`, so it not about truncating, `123412` should output `123412` by %d.

Comment: Seems be a bug of awk.

Comment: `awk '{a=(1234.12*100); printf "%d\n", a}'` also outputs wrong `123411`.

Comment: Why does `awk '{printf "%d\n", (123.12*100)}' <<<""` works?

Comment: `1234.12*100` is `123411.999999999985...`, you [saw it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76358711/unbelievable-awk-rounding-a-float-to-integer-got-weird-result-123-12100-12#comment134648333_76358711). 123411.999... truncated is 123411. `123.12*100` is exactly 12312. It's definitely not a bug.

Comment: You should read https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Round-Function.

Comment: Thank you all a lot. Understood. Just wonder why my comment of "Got it ...." was deleted? I remember I have replied.